# what software can learn the best structure of a neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Is there software out there that optimises the best combination of learning rate, weight ranges, hidden layer structure, for a certain task? After presumably trying and failing different combinations? What is this called? As far as I can tell, we just do it manually at the moment...

I know this is not differently code related but am sure it will help many others too. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The above comes under multi variate optimization problem, use an optimization algorithm and check the results. Particle Swarm Optimization would do it ( there are however considerations to use this algorithm) as long as you have a cost function to optimize for example the error rate of the network output